# Obter conteúdo de uma página utilizando XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Estou a utilizar o XMLHttpRequest para obter conteúdo de uma página. Tenho o código que funciona para criar o objeto e enviar mostrando um `alert`. Queria obter o conteúdo de uma pagina em modo `assync`.

Este é o código criando o objeto:

```
var xhr_object = null;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // Firefox
       xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) // Internet Explorer
       xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else { /
       alert("Nao suporta XMLHTTPRequest...");
       return;
    }

    //methodo de transmicao
    //url
    // true mode asynchrone
    xhr_object.open("GET", "http://page.htm", true);

    //4 (complete) 
    xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if(xhr_object.readyState == 4) alert("Request!");
    }

    //executar request
    xhr_object.send(null);
```

Comment: O que e o problema? Vc tem a alert? Não? Vc recebe datas? Idea: coloca um "else" no test sobre xhr_object.readyState == 4 ou faz um alert do resultado de readyState.

Comment: Utilizo o alert(xhr_object.responseText) mas nao mostra a data da pagina.

Comment: Estou falendo de fazer alert(xhr_object.readyState) para ler a resposto do servidor. Acho isso e o primeiro passo. Verifica tambem o URL. Porque acho "http://page.html" um pouco estranho... :)

Comment: Obtenho o valor 1, certo tirei apenas o ip do servidor.

Comment: Valor conform no W3C:
0: request not initialized
1: server connection established
2: request received
3: processing request
4: request finished and response is ready
Se vc quere ler uma pagina "local", coloca somente page.html sem o http. Ou coloca o endereço completa com IP o nome do dominio.

Comment: A conexão é estabelecida, nao consigo é mostrar o conteudo do link.

Comment: Você está respeitando a [política de mesma origem](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem)?

Comment: O request é acabado (4) e continua a não mostrar nada do alert(xhr_object.responseText); e alterei o url xhr_object.open("GET", "ip/date.php", true);

Comment: Da uma olhada no comentario de Cahe. Onde esta a sua pagina ip/date.php? No mesmo servidor que a pagina fazendo a chamada?

Comment: Tenta englobar o código com o `try/catch` e verifica qual é o erro exibido